# The Button ID does not get set to the Text of the Text Box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a text box tb and a button b, and I am trying to set the ID of the button to the text of the Text Box, however, the ID is set to empty string, and not to the string that is entered in the text box.
Need help!
Thank you.

```
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Text = "Comment";

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    String x = pno.ToString();
    b.ID = x + " " + tb.Text.ToString();
    form1.Controls.Add(tb);
    form1.Controls.Add(b);

    b.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

Answer (score 1):

`tb` is a new text box and it doesn't have any text. and don't put spaces in the `ID` field.

Comment: are you perhaps wanting to set b.Text = " " + tb.Text also text is also a string property

Comment: @DJKRAZE: `ID` is not an integer type. it is a `string`

Comment: I meant to reference the Text Property and typed differently than what I was thinking I deleted my initial